# binary operator expected error when checking if a file with full pathname exists

Tags: unix

```
pathname=$(cat $HOME/.rm.cfg)
if [ ! -z $pathname/$1 ]
```

`.rm.cfg` is a file that contains the following directory

> /home/username/deleted1

`$1` is the name of a file eg. glass

why does the line if `[ ! -z $pathname/$1 ]` give a binary operator expected error.

Answer (score 43):

I had faced the same error (**binary operator expected**) when receiving more than one word for some variable when using it as shown below:

```
if [ ! -z ${variable} ];
```

So to resolve this error I changed it to:

```
if [[ ! -z ${variable} ]];
```

Comment: great! worked for me. But any idea why the solution works?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427872/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa for brief info on [[

Answer (score 34):

Looks like your $pathname includes more than one word. Could be multiple lines in your .rm.cfg file, or perhaps the path includes spaces. Anyway, you end up with

```
if [ ! -z word word word/$1 ]
```

which is no good. If you're just expecting a single path and want to protect against the path containing whitespace, change your if line to

```
if [ ! -z "$pathname/$1" ]
```

Comment: For me, the problem was that I had a trailing space in my definition of $pathname.  I used the strip function to prevent this from happening (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)).

Comment: Accept this as answer !

Comment: Thank you! I can't tell you how many times I've been bitten by spaces in arg lists.

Answer (score 0):

When using single square brackets, double quote your variable in the test construct when intaking more than one argument. In this case, shell considers $pathname/$1 as more than one argument.